# can scanf be terminated on pressing some specific key other than enter

Tags: c, scanf

I have a situation here

i am taking input from user

using scanf  can I terminate the scanf as soon as user presses the # key

please enlighten me on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `scanf()` (or rather stdin, by default) is line-oriented so it needs to read a full line.

Look into [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) or similar libraries for "raw" key-by-key input.