# Can't stop while loop which has scanf inside

Tags: while-loop, scanf

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
        int test,i = 0,a = NULL;
        int max2 = 0;
        int n;

        int max = -1000000, min = 1000000;
        while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && max2 < 50)
        {
            if(n < min) { min = n; }     
            if(n > max) { max = n; }
            max2++;
         }
        printf("%d",min+max); 

        return 0;
    }
```

Input should be like this "1 5 8 9 10", I don't know how many numbers would be entered so I have to use the while loop.

Comment: shouldn't it be `scanf("%c", &n)` since you have `char n;` ?

Comment: I used char to try to get "\n"  to stop but it didn't work, I forgot to turn it to int but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you mean that max2 does never reach 50 and the while never stops? Because, as I see it, you will need to input 50 numbers and then it'll stop, printing out the sum of min+max

Comment: Max input numbers is 50 but It should work if I input numbers below 50.

Comment: so, you're expecting `scanf()` to return zero if you just hit <enter> without the number?

Comment: I expecting stop the while loop If I enter a line example:
1 5 8 3 4
It should return 9 to me

Comment: Could I use time functions in while, if time passed after 0.5 sec later first line sent?

Comment: I think you need to research how `scanf` works. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080872/getting-a-char-in-c-without-pressing-enter You have to hit enter at the end of each number or you have to read all the numbers at once.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `do while` to put the `scanf` inside the loop.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
        int test,i = 0,a = NULL;
        int max2 = 0;
        int n;

        int max = -1000000, min = 1000000;
        do{
            scanf("%d", &n);
            if(n < min) { min = n; }     
            if(n > max) { max = n; }
            max2++;
         }while ( n == 1 && max2 < 50)
        printf("%d",min+max); 

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It returns wrong answer
My Input: 1 5 8 9
It returns me 6 instead of 10

Comment: This would terminate the loop unless a "1" is being entered. Not quite what was intended initially by the OP.

Comment: How does this work? You lost me at `while ( n == 1 ...`